# How do I configure postfix to deliver mail to the first MX record only?

Tags: postfix, mx-record

Currently have a postfix server running as a backup mail server for several different domains. So when the primary mail server goes down, email will go to the backup server (second in the order of MX).

There is a third server in the MX also acting as a backup server in case the second fails.

I want to configure the two backup servers to only deliver the stored email to the primary when it comes back up, otherwise retain on the mail queue.

I know I could do this by adding the primary server to a transport file.  However in this case I can’t use a transport file and the servers will use the MX records from DNS.

So I want to configure the backup server to only try the *first* server in the MX order and not the others.

Can this be done?

Comment: Why can you not use transport files?

Comment: http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#backup

Answer (score 0):

Yes you *can* do this, but you would need split zone DNS or an additional local DNS server with those zones to provide only that MX to those 2 backup servers... Or use the transport configuration as suggested.  Either way you'll need some separate configuration.  You could build a DNS resolver in python to only give you a specific MX by priority, but that seems slow and overly complicated given your other 2 options.